# How to On Conflict Replace with Condition (for SQLite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL below to create a table. It will replace where the name conflict.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
    DATE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_NAME UNIQUE (NAME) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

However, I would like to replace only if the date is newer (bigger in number), or ignore the new row if the date is older. How could I alter my SQL (for SQLite) statement above to achieve that?

Comment: What should happen when it's older?

Comment: We'll drop the older version of it. Always have the latest. This is use where we are synchronizing data from various sources, where we want to preserve whatever that is newest (in Android device).

Comment: Thanks @CL for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with a table constraint, you have to use [triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) instead:

```
CREATE INDEX just_some_index ON MyTable(Name);

CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_Name_insert_newer
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT Date FROM MyTable WHERE Name = NEW.Name) <= NEW.Date
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MyTable
    WHERE Name = NEW.Name;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_Name_insert_older
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT Date FROM MyTable WHERE Name = NEW.Name) > NEW.Date
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(IGNORE);
END;
```

(In SQLite, a scalar subquery without a result returns just NULL, so inserting a new row makes both WHEN clauses fail.)